# Git checkout deploy changes over ftp

Tags: git, phpstorm

I work on local with a remote web server, putting files over ftp.
Is there a way that when I checkout a branch, the changed/deleted files will be updated automatically to the ftp deploy server?

Comment: Did you already try [this deployment feature](http://img542.imageshack.us/img542/9481/20130416230153.png)?

Comment: it worked. The problem was that my setting was "On explicit save". Now is a little bit weird because it transfers the file while I edited without saving. You saved my life :)

Comment: @CrazyCoder solution seems to work when you add resource directories (settings > directories) and only when you switch branch from the lower-right shortcut (it doesn't work if you right-click directories in the project tree and then git -> repositories -> branch)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`git-ftp`](https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp) for this. It does minimal uploads and is also able to mirror file and directory removals.